# How can i prevent page from jumping to bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The page is jumping to the bottom when the submit button is pushed on the contact form. I think this is caused by js. When you want to try it, push the link below, next contact, fill in the form and press "verstuur"

http://expertlemmer.nl/PC-laptop-reparatie-Lemmer/

javascript:

```
$('form#contactForm button.submit').on('click', function() {

      $('#image-loader').fadeIn();

      var contactFname = $('#contactForm #contactFname').val();
      var contactLname = $('#contactForm #contactLname').val();
      var contactStraat = $('#contactForm #contactStraat').val();
      var contactPostcode = $('#contactForm #contactPostcode').val();
      var contactTel = $('#contactForm #contactTel').val();
      var contactEmail = $('#contactForm #contactEmail').val();
      var contactSubject = $('#contactForm #contactSubject').val();
      var contactMessage = $('#contactForm #contactMessage').val();

      var data = 'contactFname=' + contactFname  + '&contactLname=' + contactLname +
                 '&contactEmail=' + contactEmail + '&contactSubject=' + contactSubject +
                 '&contactStraat=' + contactStraat  + '&contactPostcode=' + contactPostcode  +
                 '&contactTel=' + contactTel  + '&contactMessage=' + contactMessage;

      $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "inc/sendEmail.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(msg) {

            // Message was sent
            if (msg == 'OK') {
               $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
               $('#message-warning').hide();
               $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
               $('#message-success').fadeIn();
            }
            // There was an error
            else {
               $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
               $('#message-warning').html(msg);
              $('#message-warning').fadeIn();
            }

        }

      });
      return false;
});
```

Comment: It jumps to the top on mine?

Comment: In what browser - looks fine to me in Chrome?

Comment: On your website you have `e.preventDefault()`, but there's no `e` parameter to the function so that gets an error and the rest of the function is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i was on your webpage. And you are using in your script :

```
$('form#contactForm button.submit').on('click', function() {
   e.preventDefault();
// and so on
```

The problem is that, you do not pass the e in the function. You have to use it like this :

```
$('form#contactForm button.submit').on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
    // and so on
```

Then it will prevent the form from refreshing the page. I am just guessing that you want to send the form through ajax.

Comment: I stand corrected, Rednif is correct, Refresh your cache (ctrl+r on chrome/windows), it should work fine now

Comment: @SanderZijnstra so the problem is still there? Or  did my answer help you? If my answer helped you please check it as right, if no just tell me what problem you are experiencing now.

Answer (score 0):

Your form has no "ACTION" attribute, this means it's posting to the current URL. The current URL has an anchor : #contact, this means you'll jump straight to the contact part.

See what you get when you go into this link and scroll down(Scroll, don't click contact), you'll jump to the review section.

http://expertlemmer.nl/PC-laptop-reparatie-Lemmer/#journal

Long story short, Put an action tag on your form :)

Comment: It acts the same when i try this, so it also jumps to the almost the bottom. What should the action tag be? When i use a href it acts the same.